# Error casted by simple mutate using tidyverse or dplyr

Tags: r, error-handling, rstudio, tidyverse, dplyr

I am having serious troubles using the tidyverse package that I cannot debug. As an example, "mutate" does not work properly even on past project I have already produced.
This all started when I installed the following package:

```
library(pdftools)
library(tm)
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
```

(or `library(dplyr)
library(tidyr))
library(purrr)`)

And it still remains when I do a `rm(list=ls())`.

The only thing I haven't tried so forth is deinstalling R/RStudio and reinstalling it.
I use RStudio version 1.0.153 and R version 3.4.1.
I actually tried to reproduce the bug on other computers and this was obviously not working.

Here is an ad hoc example:

```
library(tidyverse)
emp.data <- data.frame(emp_id=c(1:5),emp_name=c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
                       salary=c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25), 
                       start_date=as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2013-09-23", "2014-11-15", "2014-05-11",
                         "2015-03-27"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
)
emp.data_new <- emp.data %>%
  mutate(RaisedSalary = salary*1.4)
```

emp.data is defined ok in my session. I would expect the addition of a new column in the new data frame emp.data.new ("RaisedSalary") and instead of this I get:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>    Cannot convert object to a function: [type=NULL; target=CLOSXP, SPECIALSXP, or BUILTINSXP].

I also get this error message if I load tidyr/dplyr instead of tidyverse. I've lurked on the forum for more than 48 hours without finding anything close to this mistake. Has anyone already experienced such an error?

Outcome of sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] wordcloud_2.6      RColorBrewer_1.1-2 SnowballC_0.6.0    bindrcpp_0.2       forcats_0.3.0      stringr_1.4.0      purrr_0.3.2        readr_1.1.1       
 [9] tibble_1.4.2       ggplot2_3.0.0      tidyverse_1.2.1    tidyr_0.8.0        dplyr_0.7.4        stringi_1.4.3      tm_0.7-6           NLP_0.2-0         
[17] pdftools_2.2       GCPM_1.2.2        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] qpdf_1.1           tidyselect_0.2.4   slam_0.1-45        reshape2_1.4.2     haven_1.1.1        lattice_0.20-35    colorspace_1.3-2   rlang_0.4.0       
 [9] pillar_1.2.2       foreign_0.8-69     glue_1.2.0         withr_2.1.2        modelr_0.1.1       readxl_1.1.0       bindr_0.1          plyr_1.8.4        
[17] munsell_0.5.0      gtable_0.2.0       cellranger_1.1.0   rvest_0.3.2        psych_1.8.3.3      parallel_3.4.1     broom_0.4.4        Rcpp_0.12.16      
[25] scales_1.0.0       jsonlite_1.5       RcppProgress_0.4.1 mnormt_1.5-5       askpass_1.1        hms_0.3            grid_3.4.1         cli_1.0.0         
[33] tools_3.4.1        magrittr_1.5       lazyeval_0.2.0     crayon_1.3.4       pkgconfig_2.0.1    xml2_1.1.1         lubridate_1.7.4    assertthat_0.2.0  
[41] httr_1.4.0         rstudioapi_0.7     R6_2.2.2           nlme_3.1-131       compiler_3.4.1
```

Comment: Your code runs fine for me.  I'm definitely using much newer versions of R and RStudio, but it looks like, e.g., **dplyr** should work on R versions as old as 3.2. Can you add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your question so we can see package versions?

Comment: What package did you install? Is it possible that you accidentally updated your `rlang` package (possibly as a dependency of another package)? Or one of the other dependencies of dplyr?

Comment: @AdamSampson
To your concern: I recently installed pdftools, tm and stringi and it's highly probable that rlang has been updated alongside those installations.

Answer (score 2):

Got this error with ver 3.5 in script that had previously worked - Updating rlang fixed issue

Comment: I also think this was the biggest issue here.

Answer (score 2):

I updated the dplyr by using install.packages("dplyr") and it worked. Except that now it gives me warning messages that rlang is not compatible with dplyr now. Still, it worked! Hope they will sort out the incompatibility soon. --- 2019/09/17

Comment: this worked for me. it installed all the dependent packages as well like purr and rlang. no error message after